# How do I cause a line break when writing code in latex with predetermined line numbers?

Tags: color, code

[image]

I currently have my pdf looking like this but I want lines 30 and 31 to be green as well. I was wondering if someone knows of a way I can do this?

Here is my Latex

```
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item [\textbf{Example 1:}]
    \begin{lstlisting}[firstnumber=1]
    int digitOfPi(int n){
        /*
         * Code not shown
    \end{lstlisting}
    ~~$\vdots$\\
    \begin{lstlisting}[firstnumber=30]
         */
         }
    \end{lstlisting}
```

Comment: Welcome! Please complete your example so it can be compiled. That will be much more useful than a mere fragment.

Answer (score 1):

The following example provides a workaround for this case. It adds a line comment starting with `*` to format the ending comment marker as comment. The closing curly brace is left untouched, because it does *not* belong to the comment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\colorlet{darkgreen}{green!70!black}
\lstset{
  basicstyle=\ttfamily,
  commentstyle=\color{darkgreen},
  identifierstyle=\color{blue},
  numbers=left,
}

\begin{document}
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item [\textbf{Example 1:}] \mbox{}\\
\begin{lstlisting}[language=C, firstnumber=1]
int digitOfPi(int n) {
    /*
     * Code not shown
\end{lstlisting}
\vspace{-3ex}
\begin{lstlisting}[mathescape, numbers=none]
     $\vdots$
\end{lstlisting}
\vspace{-2ex}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=C, firstnumber=30, morecomment={[l]{*}}]
     */
}
\end{lstlisting}
  \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]